# Open Refine is showing a blank blue screen and I cannot upload any data to clean. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Tags: data-cleaning, openrefine

[OpenRefine screen without option to upload data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tXStM.jpg)
Open Refine is showing a blank blue screen. I can't upload any data to clean. Java is updated and it's the newest version (3.4.1). How can I fix this so I can upload data to clean? I'm not sure if it's the port I'm using or something else.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to clean the refine support folder, the issue you are telling is most probably due to some corrupted data loaded in a project or either refine was disturbed while gracefully shutting down.
Refine support folder resides in `Library/Application support/refine` for macOS>

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm using Windows...where would the folder be? It wouldn't be the batch folder I'm assuming?

Comment: Hi @Jennylj78, The workspace directory for windows are 
`C:\Documents and Settings\(user id)\Local Settings\Application Data\OpenRefine;
C:\Users\(user id)\AppData\Roaming\OpenRefine;
C:\Users\(user id)\AppData\Local\OpenRefine;
C:\Users\(user id)\OpenRefine;`
depending upon the version of windows, it varies from the above four listed. Please find the workspace directory and delete it. Then restart the openrefine and it will work like charm.